# Render API response body content with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Working with Node.js, I wrote a router implementation as follows:

```
router.get('/fileshare', oauth2.required, (req, res, next) => {
  var apiResponse = null;

  // Consume GCP API
  const queryObject = {
    project: config.get('GCLOUD_PROJECT'),
    prefix: 'msf-test-fs'
  };
  request.get({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b',
    qs: queryObject,
    auth: {
      'bearer': req.user.token
    }
  }, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      self.callback(err, null);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res.body); // Has content
    apiResponse = res.body
  });
  // Render content

  // I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE HERE THE API RESPONSE BODY!!!
  console.log(apiResponse); // Is null
  res.render('pages/list', { }); // <<-- response body here as param
});
```

It basically invoke an API endpoint and retrieve an response body.
I would now like to pass the API response body to render a webpage.

However, the `apiResponse` is `null` while invoking `console.log(apiResponse);`.

How could I fix it?

Comment: You are setting `apiResponse` in an async function and the code below it is executed before `request.get()` has finished

Comment: How can I rewrite this code in order to make sync it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback invoked by `request` is called asynchronously after `res.render`. You need to move `res.render` to the callback and stop shadowing `res` variable.

```
router.get('/fileshare', oauth2.required, (req, res, next) => {

  // Consume GCP API
  const queryObject = {
    project: config.get('GCLOUD_PROJECT'),
    prefix: 'msf-test-fs'
  };
  request.get({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b',
    qs: queryObject,
    auth: {
      'bearer': req.user.token
    }
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      self.callback(err, null);
      return;
    }
    console.log(response.body); // Has content

    // Render content

    console.log(response.body); 
    res.render('pages/list', JSON.parse(response.body)); // <<-- response body here as param
  });
});
```

Comment: I did try this solution, however I got the following error: https://gist.github.com/vdenotaris/ccc8e59985042d671cf5cd60bb32c122

Comment: You should add 'res.render('pages/list', JSON.parse(response.body))' response body is just a string. I will Edit my answer.